# Full Screen Image with Text/Button (Responsive)

Tags: css, image, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am working on a sophisticated project for a client. I have designed a full screen landing page will need to be compatible across all sized windows/mobile (responsive). Currently I cannot target the image to cover the entire page. The div (slider-full-width) needs to span the entire window. I have supplied an image to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. I am using the Skeleton Framework. http://www.getskeleton.com/ You must be able to keep scrolling down to see the rest of the page content after this full screen landing page.

[image: This has to occupy the entire screen on all devices]

My HTML:

```
  <div id="slider-full-width">
<div class="container">
  <h2>Seeking a refreshening management service?</h2>
  <h2>You've come to the right place</h2>
  <div id="button-bg">
  <a href="properties.html" class="presentation-button">Properties</a>
  <a href="#body-span-class" class="presentation-button">See why</a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    #slider-full-width{
width: 100%;
background-image: url('../img/slide-01.jpg');
position:relative;
text-align: center;}
    #slider-full-width h2 {
color: #efefef;
```

}

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it left that gap of whitespace at the top, but I've created a jsfiddle for you to show what I did to remove it: http://jsfiddle.net/sKzCc/

**HTML:**

> ```
> <div id="slider-full-width"> <div class="container">   <h2>Seeking a
> refreshening management service?</h2>   <h2>You've come to the right
> place</h2>   <div id="button-bg">   <a href="properties.html"
> class="presentation-button">Properties</a>
>   <a href="#body-span-class" class="presentation-button">See why</a>   </div>
> ```

**CSS:**

> ```
> #slider-full-width{ max-width: 100%; min-height:800px; background: url('http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk/image/two.jpg') no-repeat center
> center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size:
> cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
> position:relative; text-align: center; } #slider-full-width h2 {
> color: #efefef; margin-top:-20px; font-size: 25.29pt; padding-top:
> 285px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; }
> ```

I added in the `background-size:cover` tags for all major browsers to ensure maximum cross-browser compatibility.
I hope this solution works for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have the background image cover the div you could use this in your selector:

```
#slider-full-width {
    /* Your code */
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: That didn't help :( I need the div (#slider-full-widt) to span the entire window with no gaps etc. and Ive checked the source image it is large enough.

Comment: So the div is not spanning the full width? Change your width to max-width: 100%.

Comment: Its spanning the full width just not the vertical height. The image is consuming 1/6 of the page (y axis/vertical) instead of all of it. Do I use a height: 100% ?

Comment: The div is only going to take up as much space that the content needs. You could use `min-height: insert height needed;` It will still be responsive as well

Comment: Thank you! I used a pixel value (because percentage didn't work). The very last question of this topic the text is sitting at the top of the page causing a big white strip. What is the most logical way of dropping this text down 285pixels?

Comment: `padding-top:285px;` or position the div vertically center

Comment: Ok that worked, but there's still a big white strip at the top of the page that pushes the background image down approximately 50px. How to get rid of this?

Comment: @JOG-Design Can you post your container div `css` please? You're using div id's and classes simultaneously, I tend to avoid this. Plus your container and button-bg div's don't have closing `div` tags.

Comment: @adaam That was a copy and paste issue with the closing div tags, they are there.
`#slider-full-width{
 max-width: 100%;
 min-height: 800px;
 background-image: url('../img/slide-01.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 position:relative;
 text-align: center;
}
#slider-full-width h2 {
 color: #efefef;
 font-size: 25.29pt;
 padding-top: 285px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
} `